# flutter's AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin doesn't keep the page state after navigator.push

Tags: flutter, dart

was testing AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and run into an issue,
page loses state after navigator.push
anyone knows this issue? any workarounds? be glad for any info, cheers

my goal is to keep the page state

steps to reproduce: open app click PageOne's push-button then go back swipe right and left and the page loses state
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQKe8.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 0,
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[Page1(), Page2()],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Material(
            child: TabBar(
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Page1State createState() {
    return new Page1State();
  }
}

class Page1State extends State<Page1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.pink,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(height: 26,
              child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child:
                      Text('clicking this and back then swipe => page loses state'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PushedPage()),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(height: 300, color: Colors.orange);
  }
}

class PushedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why you say it lose the state?

Comment: Because the listview position is reset to the beginning after push, back, swipe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702330/10269042

Comment: Sorry @anmol.majhail I didn't quite understand, you mean I should add super.Build(context); to the build?

Comment: yes - Before `return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[` add - `super.Build(context);`

Comment: indeed it works @anmol.majhail thumbs up!

Comment: added it as answer

Answer (score 65):

From the documentation on [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html):

> A mixin with convenience methods for clients of
> [AutomaticKeepAlive]. Used with [State] subclasses.
>
> Subclasses must implement [wantKeepAlive], and their [build]
> methods must call super.build (the return value will always return
> null, and should be ignored).

So in your code, before you return the ListView just call super.build:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return ListView(...
  }
```