# How do I prevent the state of my application from changing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on this application but I just realised that when the boxes are checked and I scroll up and down, it unchecks itself. Meaning the state of the application is changing.

I used gridview.builder for the gridview which is working very fine except the fact that when i checked those bozes, scroll up and down, the boxes unchecked itself. Please a quick fix will be appreciated. Thank you.

Please how do I fix this? This is my code below:

```
class GridViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridViewPageState createState() => _GridViewPageState();
}

class _GridViewPageState extends State<GridViewPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 125.0),
              child: Product(),
            ),
          ),
          HeaderWiget(),
          Center(
              child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 64.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0XFF161F51).withOpacity(0.4),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Next',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Work Sans',
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HeaderWiget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colors = Color(0XFF161F51);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 128,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colors,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'What do you do?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 28.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'You can select multiple options',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                          text: 'SKIP',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Work Sans',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            decorationColor: Colors.white,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          ))
                    ],
                  ))),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class Product extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductState createState() => _ProductState();
}

class _ProductState extends State<Product> {
  final listItem = [
    {'Name': 'Hair & Beauty', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle15.png'},
    {'Name': 'Wedding planner', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle16.png'},
    {'Name': 'Bridal Attire', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle17.png'},
    {'Name': 'Catering_1', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle18.png'},
    {'Name': 'DJ', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle19.png'},
    {'Name': 'Florist', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle20.png'},
    {'Name': 'Jewelry', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle21.png'},
    {'Name': 'Props', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle22.png'},
    {'Name': 'Bridal_Attire', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle17.png'},
    {'Name': 'Catering', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle18.png'},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: listItem.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: ProductApp(
                  businessName: listItem[index]['Name'],
                  businessImage: listItem[index]['image'],
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
}

class ProductApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final businessName;
  final businessImage;
  ProductApp({this.businessName, this.businessImage});
  @override
  _ProductAppState createState() => _ProductAppState();
}

class _ProductAppState extends State<ProductApp> {
  Color color;
  var isToggle = false;
  ColorFilter filterColor = ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey, BlendMode.saturation);
  ColorFilter normalFilter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
          tag: widget.businessName,
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isToggle = isToggle ? false : true;
                });
              },
              child: GridTile(
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: ExactAssetImage(widget.businessImage),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      colorFilter: isToggle ? normalFilter : filterColor),
                )),
                header: Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    trailing: SelectedDot(
                        colors: isToggle
                            ? Colors.pink
                            : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0)),
                    title: Text(
                      widget.businessName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 12.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58921956/1656813) helps?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a gridview.builder which has its performance optimizations during scrolls over items. It automatically removes and creates elements that out of the screen or on it now. In your code, you're saving state inside a ProductApp stateful widget, but it's statefulness doesn't mean anything in case of building inside of a gridview.builder. These widgets were just rebuilt after you clicked on this 'checkbox' and scrolled up or down.

The best solution will be remove state from component and use state management tools like Provider or Bloc packages. Quickly, you can lift state of value up in a widget tree to pass into gridview elements only state and onChange callback.

```
GridView.builder(
          itemCount: listItem.length,
          gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: ProductApp(
                  isToggled: YourItemObject.isToggled,
                  onChange: YourItemObject.onChange,
                  businessName: YourItemObject.name,
                  businessImage: YourItemObject.image,
                ));
          })
```

In this way, your gridview.builder element will receive only the value and way to change it. But the value itself now are managing outside of grid items.